# Kubuntu Widgets in Ubuntu

Tags: desktop-environments

I'm using Kubuntu, but by default my laptop has Ubuntu 13.10 on it.

I'm wondering if I can get the same desktop widgets

I have on the KUbuntu Environment on Ubuntu desktop?

Everything on it I want exactly that on Ubuntu. No Screenlets.

Screenshot:

[image: picture]